# Three navigation menu and circular navigation in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

In my Windows Phone 7.5 (Mango) app I have this situation. I have to use 3 menu buttons that navigates to separate section of the app something like shown in image below:
[image]

Clicking on A takes to page A, On B takes to B and same for C.

Page A displays other buttons that takes user to A specific section/pages.
Same for Page B and Page C.

**Issue/Question:**
I am sure this is going to cause circular navigation issue when using BackButton. I would like to know the best way to handle this scenario.

**One way** I can think of is clearing the BackStack, I know how to do this but want to know if there's a better way out.

**Pivot Page:** I am not sure if I should use Pivot Control.

Other complex way: Use a common page and hide controls based on button click i.e. instead of navigating to new page, simply show control related to the A or B or C and hide unrelated stuff. I am not sure if this is a good way as I have few images and animation specific to each page and seems to be complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivout isn't going to fit my needs due to some other design issues.

So I scrapped out the idea of using menus like above and instead created a separte page(home) that will have 3 buttons to navigate and if user wants to change the section, they go to home and select from there.

Answer (score 1):

The better user experience, would be to use a Pivot. Users hate clicking buttons. Look at how all other applications for Windows Phone works, and you'll see what's considered the intuitive/native experience.

Comment: Thanks. I will have to look into Pivots but for now I think I am going to move my 3 buttons to a separate page. So if user is on A and needs to go to Section B or C they just GoBack and select from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle/override/consume the back button pressed event when the user navigates along a specific path. You can use [NavigationServce.RemoveBackEntry()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry.aspx) to remove the most recent journal entry.

In one of your pages(or all, depending on your navigation possibilities),this code on the pages' onNavigatedTo() handler can solve the circular navigation woes. You can also put **markers** in your query string which help in identifying the route the user chooses to navigate

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e){
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PageA.xaml?fromPageC=true"));
}

public override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New && NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("resultsInCircular")
{
    NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry(); // might have to repeat this a number of times        depending on the route that the user has taken
})
}
```